# How can I tell if a ref is being updated by a dosync in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have some updates which need to be made to a ref, but I want to choose a time to perform the updates when the ref is not in heavy use. Is there a way I can programatically tell when the ref is in a transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could `add-watch` that would update an access-time each time your ref is written (you mentions it was write mostly). This would give you a huristic for busy.

```
(def my-ref (ref {}))
(def my-ref-atime (atom 0))
(add-watch my-ref (fn [key ref old new] (swap! my-ref-atime current-time-fn))))
```

then only do low priority work when atime is more than 10ms in the past.

Comment: Correct and simple. When I saw this answer it was one of those "Why didn't I think of that!" moments. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You may be asking a single identity to do too much. Consider having two identities: one that has high write volume, and another (possibly derivative) identity that is updated occasionally.

Your approach already implies that the occasional updates aren't part of the ref's timeline, since you are willing to defer them.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to use a [ref](http://clojure.org/refs) and not an [agent](http://clojure.org/agents)?

It sounds to me like you want to perform updates, but you don't care about when the updates actually happen (just so long as they happen eventually).  This is exactly what `agents` are used for: sharing state in an asynchronous and independent manner.  `Refs` are for sharing state in a synchronous and coordinated manner.

Structuring application logic around whether or not a ref is in a transaction sounds like a bad idea to me.  Maybe if you provide more details someone can come up with a better design.

Comment: I do care about when the updates happen for some of the transactions as there are alot of writes. I want some not so important updates to happen when the ref is not so busy so as to reduce contention.

Comment: A good point about rethinking the design too... I'll think more about this